# How to disable Gmail (web) attachment preview?

Tags: gmail, google-drive-api, attachment

I find the preview of attached image is quiet annoying, especially when you have lots of them.

Is there **anyway to turn off** these previews?

Comment: I agree that this question should be migrated to Superuser.com.

Comment: Related question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129443/disable-gmail-attachment-preview

Answer (score 2):

You may use old Gmail interface if you access it at

http://mail.google.com/?ui=html

It is much less annoying: it lets you see the complete file name and size and download attachments directly skipping the awful Drive thing.